# Strike the Element using Id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to strike all the text based on the element id using javascript.

How to do this?

Comment: are you using jQuery? and what is the element id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to go using vanilla javascript should be just to manipulate the HTML content itself. This could look like:

```
var targetElem = document.getElementById('myid');

targetElem.innerHTML = '<strike>' + targetElem.innerHTML + '</strike>';
```

Using jQuery, this task becomes only slightly more trivial by using `.contents()` +  `.wrapAll()`:

```
$('#myid').contents().wrapAll('<strike/>');
```

Another alternative, using css might also be an idea:

```
targetElem.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
```

Or again using jQuery to be more cross-browser compliant:

```
$('#myid').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
```

Comment: i think the last option is the best

Comment: Why is CSS a last alternative?

Comment: @Felix: I didn't mean it like this. What I was trying to say is, the last thing "on my little list" there.

Comment: Really chance less :) You are great :) I didn't expect this much of options:) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

something like

```
document.getElementById('foo').style.textDecoration ='line-through';
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.strike{
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery("#yourid").addClass("strike");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your ID in place of `yourID`

This will be simple if you are using JQuery.

```
$("#yourID").css("textDecoration", "line-through");
```

If not using JQuery.

```
var element = document.getElementById('yourID');
element.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
```

But i am not sure if it will work for all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the text contained in the tag and add a long strikethrough in the middle of each letter:

```js
var targetElem = document.getElementById('myId');
var oldSting = targetElem.textContent

var strikeString = oldSting.split('').join('̶') + '̶';

targetElem.textContent = strikeString;
```

```html
<p id="myId">some text</p>
```